# Check that one and only one optional function parameter is set and get its value

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have the following function

```
def foo(a, b=None, c=None, d=None)
```

where of the optional parameters `b`, `c`, and `d` one and only one should be set to a numeric value (zero not allowed). The function should also accept other optional parameters, which I left out of the definition for the sake of clarity.

To check this, I get the lists of the parameter values and names as such:

```
def foo(a, b=None, c=None, d=None):
    print(locals().keys())
    print(locals().values())
```

which gives e.g.:

```
foo(a=1, b=2)
-
dict_keys(['d', 'c', 'b', 'a'])
dict_values([None, None, 2, 1])
```

as expected. The following list comprehension should then check the optional parameters against their value and only return the parameter with a true value.

```
fov_arg = [(arg, list(locals().values())[i]) for i, arg in enumerate(locals().keys() \
           if arg in ['b', 'c', 'd'] and list(locals().values())[i]]
```

I could then `assert len(fov_arg) == 1` to see that one and only one of the optional parameters was set. The `locals().values()` is wrapped into the `list()` call as I am using python3.6, where `locals().values()` returns a dict view, not a list.

However, running the function with the list comprehension

```
def foo(a, b=None, c=None, d=None):
    print(locals().keys())
    print(locals().values())

    fov_arg = [(arg, list(locals().values())[i]) for i, arg in enumerate(locals().keys() \
           if arg in ['b', 'c', 'd'] and list(locals().values())[i]]

foo(a=1, b=2)
```

outputs the following:

```
dict_keys(['d', 'c', 'b', 'a'])
dict_values([None, None, 2, 1])

[('d', 'd'), ('c', 1), ('b', <enumerate object at 0x7fd90c43ba20>)]
```

I expected the output to be `[(b, 2)]`. I do not understand why `d` and `c` are in this list, as their values are `None`. In addition, both of them show the wrong values, and the value of `b` is an `enumerate object`.

To figure out what is going wrong, I rewrote the list comprehension into

```
for i, arg in enumerate(locals().keys()):
        if arg in ['b', 'c', 'd']:
            if list(locals().values())[i]:
                print(arg, list(locals().values())[i])
```

Calling the function with the same arguments as above gives me

```
File "test.py", line 3, in foo
    for i, arg in enumerate(locals().keys()):
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I see that the dictionary `locals().keys()` seems to be involved in the problem, but I do not understand what is going wrong and how I can fix this behaviour.

Comment: I would simplify the problem to accepting `**kwargs`, checking that its `len` is `1` and maybe that its only key is `in 'bcd'`…!?

Comment: @Chris_Rands That is not enough as it does not provide the set parameter and its value

Comment: @deceze The function also has other optional parameters, so that will not work. I will add that to the question

Comment: Use `**kwargs` and then use `[(name, value)] = list(kwargs.items())`.

Comment: Why use `locals()`? Why not just `{'b': b, ...}`?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, that is way better. Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is going wrong

The `locals()` dictionary is updated every time you create a local variable. In particular, after you call `enumerate(locals().keys())` and before you call `locals().values())[i]`, you create the local variables `i` and `arg`. Therefore, the dict that the former returns has different membership than the dict that the latter returns.

Similarly, in your `for` loop:

```
for i, arg in enumerate(locals().keys()):
```

During the first iteration, `locals()` has only `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`. By the second iteration, it also has `i` and `arg`.

> and how I can fix this behaviour.

Choose a simpler way of interpreting your arguments. May I suggest:

```
sum(i is not None for i in [b, c, d]) == 1
```

Other, potentially better, solutions are listed in the comments.

Comment: @tobias_k - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `**kwargs` is not an option, following up on @Rob's answer, perhaps the following variation works:

```
def foo(a, b=None, c=None, d=None):
    localvars = locals()
    fov_arg = [(arg,localvars[arg]) for arg in localvars.keys()\
    if arg in ['b', 'c', 'd'] and localvars[arg]]
```

I've simplified your comprehension a bit, I think the `enumerate`, in particular, is avoidable.

Answer (score 0):

I propose to do all the checks in one simple call:

```
def foo(a, **kwargs):
    [(name, value)] = list(kwargs.items())
    assert name in 'bcd'
    # now process a, name, and value
```

Now you have to pass `a` and exactly one additional argument to the function, otherwise the assignment will fail.  The name of the additional argument needs to be one of `b`, `c`, `d`, otherwise the `assert` will fail.

This way it gets less cluttered and you have the name of the additional argument in the `name` variable.

If you have other optional parameters, they can easily go along with this:

```
def foo(a, some_other_optional_parameter=some_default_value, **kwargs):
    [(name, value)] = list(kwargs.items())
    assert name in 'bcd'
    # now process a, name, value, and some_other_optional_parameter
```

This can be called either as

```
foo(4, c=5)
```

or as

```
foo(4, c=5, some_other_optional_parameter=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a specific signature to declare the arguments and then define the function to accept `*kwargs`. The nice point is that the signature will be used by  any smart editor to suggest the correct parameters, and the `inspect` module will be able to automatically check its correctness for an easier maintenance.

The drawback is that it will need customization when you add additional keyword parameters:

```
def foo(a, *, b=None, c=None, d=None):   # force b, c, and d to be passed by keyword
    pass

sig = inspect.signature(foo)

def foo(a, *args, **kwargs):
    if len(kwargs) != 1 or len(args) != 0 
        or (tuple(kwargs.values()))[0] is None):
        raise ValueError("1 and only 1 of b,c, d parameters required")
    bound = sig.bind_partial(a, *args, **kwargs)
    bound.apply_defaults()

    # actual processing...
    def do_process(a, b, c, d):
        print("foo", a, b, c, d)
    do_process(**bound.arguments)

foo.__signature__ = sig
```

It works rather well:

```
>>> foo(1, c=2)
foo 1 None 2 None
>>> foo(a =1, b=3)
foo 1 3 None None
>>> foo(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#136>", line 1, in <module>
    foo(1)
  File "<pyshell#132>", line 4, in foo
    raise ValueError("1 and only 1 of b,c, d parameters required")
ValueError: 1 and only 1 of b,c, d parameters required
>>> foo(1, b=2, c=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#137>", line 1, in <module>
    foo(1, b=2, c=3)
  File "<pyshell#132>", line 4, in foo
    raise ValueError("1 and only 1 of b,c, d parameters required")
ValueError: 1 and only 1 of b,c, d parameters required
>>> foo(a=1, d=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#138>", line 1, in <module>
    foo(a=1, d=None)
  File "<pyshell#132>", line 4, in foo
    raise ValueError("1 and only 1 of b,c, d parameters required")
ValueError: 1 and only 1 of b,c, d parameters required
```